# Search is substituting "generate" for "generic"

Tags: bug, search

Today, I tried to search for [`[java] generic answers:0 is:question closed:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+generic+answers%3A0+is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0) (clickable link), and found that all of the results that showed involved the word *generate* as opposed to *generic* or *generics*. Is this some sort of fuzzy searching going on?

I also tried `[java] generic -generate answers:0 is:question closed:0` which resulted in no results (presumably because it was removing `generic`). However, there are questions with no answers that are not closed on generics in the java tag.

Can I work around this somehow?

Comment: Putting "" quotes around generic seems to help (or at least gets rid of some generates). Very odd bug :/ looks like generate has slipped into the list of words deemed interchangeable with generic

Comment: Probably just a dumb stemmer rather than lists of equivalent words...

Comment: Fair, I had no idea how these things work. I wasn't trying to make a guess at the implementation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too-localized since the issue in question seems to have been resolved, without a status-resolved tag on this post itself.